# Shapefile stopped displaying polygons and gives error: 'No extent could be determined' in QGIS 3.10

Tags: qgis, shapefile, qgis-3, error, extents

I have been using a shapefile as a main data layer since Jan 2018 in a project, it forms the basis of several duplicate layers, it has been working fine until today.

Now 95% of the polygons are no longer showing, even though they still exist in the attribute table. If I select one and `Zoom to Selection` I receive an error message ***Cannot zoom to selected feature(s): No extent could be determined***

[image]

This happened after I deleted a few polygons and copied some others across from another shapefile. This other shapefile was a direct copy of same layer from a few weeks ago that I was using as a temporary working layer.

As I have this direct copy I can repair things in my project by working back and resetting up the duplicate layers with their different styles. But things have moved on since this copy and I am trying to find a solution that reverses what has happened to this shapefile.

I have used the *Vector > Geometry Tools > Check validity...* (both QGIS and GEOS) I found one digitising error which was fixed.

I have searched here on GIS Stack Exchange and found a few questions mentioning 'No extent could be determined' but none of them are relevant to this scenario.

Now I do tend to use Geopackages and PostGIS databases for my work. It just happens that this particular project is legacy and old and it hasn't been updated yet.

Any quick and easy way to fix this shapefile?

I am in CRS EPSG: 27700 British National Grid

**EDIT:** Subsequent to the comments I can confirm that I do also receive the error ***Cannot use preferred transform between EPSG: 4326 and EPSG: 27700***

[image]

Comment: possibly related: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/30643 (and similar issues).

Comment: Please, create a new string type field and populate it with the `geom_to_wkt($geometry)` expression, and include the smallest WKT string of a conflictive geometry.

Comment: Could the .shp file be corrupted? Can you try to rebuild the spatial index?

Comment: It seems to be QGIS bug , see edit, I did try rebuilding the spatial index, but this didn't work. I am not sure there is an answer to my question then, other than to avoid QGIS 3.8 onwards for users of EPSG:27700 - I may as well leave the question up though as a sign post to others that may encounter something similar. Is it worth adding this as an answer so it leaves the unanswered que?

Comment: I can confirm this happens regardless of the CRS your in. I'm using EPSG: 2039 and the same happened, the layer has all the data but will not show up no matter what I do. It happened after I did some basic calculation in the calculator. Anyway from what I understand the geometry is deleted for some reason and cannot be respawned, though as you said the data remains. Better have some cloud service next time so you can recover it like I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a problem only with users of EPSG: 27700 in users of QGIS 3.8 onwards as it seems to be related to a bug https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/30643 (link supplied by @nmtoken in the comments).

When opening QGIS I do receive the error

`Cannot use preferred transform between EPSG: 4326 and EPSG: 27700`

It comes with a window to 'Select Transform for..' and there is a link in the details of the error to osgeo.org for a grid file. You can download and install the missing grid file and restart QGIS and set this transformation to default.

[image]

[image]

However the damage had been done to the shapefile in my case, so I restored it using QGIS 3.4

My answer to my question for now  is that I will avoid using QGIS 3.8 onwards until I am aware that this bug has been fixed.

Comment: Does anyone know if this has been fixed now? How does one find out?