# Last record of a shapefile not visible on the map

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I am trying to load a .shp in QGIS, specifically a line .shp. Weird thing is that when loading it shows all the lines (records) except the last record (the one with the highest ID record). I tried with other .shp and it does the same. I also checked with other GIS software and all the lines are displayed.

When opening the attribute table the record is there with all it's attributes, but it's not plotted on the map. When selecting "zoom to feature" from the attribute table, this message shows up: cannot zoom to selected feature: no extent could be determined.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

A similar bug is discussed here:

[Shapefile stopped displaying polygons and gives error: 'No extent could be determined' in QGIS 3.10](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/349133/shapefile-stopped-displaying-polygons-and-gives-error-no-extent-could-be-deter)

It seems like the bug should be fixed in the newest QGIS version, so you can try to install it and try with that. Otherwise, use an even older version (pre 3.8) or change the projection of your data with a different software.